# What is the earliest paper in which local edge connectivity was defined?

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $E$. The Local edge connectivity $\lambda(x,y;G)$  for $x,y\in V$ with $x\neq y$  is defined as the least number $|F|$ such that $x$ and $y$ are disconnected in $G-F$, where $F\subseteq E$.

When was the concept of local edge connectivity introduced? More specifically, I would like to know the paper in which this concept was introduced. I have not been able to trace it to its base article.